# 'sold at an auction' or 'sold in an auction' [or ...]?

Tags: grammar

I was asked what preposition should be used in the following sentence in an English exam:

> The antique furniture was sold _______ an auction.

I think it should be 'at an auction', but several students told me 'in' is more appropriate.

Can anyone please say which one is correct (in/at) and explain why?

Comment: Both are possible. The antique furniture was sold at an auction. (at gives the location of the sale) OR The antique furniture was sold in an auction. (in is approximately the same as "during [the course of]")

Comment: so can you please say which one is more appropriate or both are the same in this case

Comment: An English exam deciding that one was 'correct' and the other 'incorrect' should probably be looked at in the light of [these Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sold+at+an+auction%2Csold+in+an+auction%2Csold+at+auction&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csold%20at%20an%20auction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csold%20in%20an%20auction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csold%20at%20auction%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csold%20at%20an%20auction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csold%20in%20an%20auction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csold%20at%20auction%3B%2Cc0); they ...

Comment: show that though both 'sold at an auction' and 'sold in an auction' are actually used and thus quite probably acceptable (and @Greybeard explains different shades of meaning), with 'sold at an auction' being the more common (there being a ratio of about 5 : 1), both seem far less idiomatic than 'sold at auction'.

Comment: For your information, the idiomatic usage here is: **sold at auction**. And there is also a lovely verb: was auctioned off.

Comment: Yes. Though _auction off_ has other senses; _auction_ is usable as a single verb, a location (hence the _at_ locative preposition), a social or commercial event, an individual transaction, or (as always) a name.